# Testing for difference in means with bimodally distributed data?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, distributions, t-test, inference, bimodal

I have two bimodal distributions of data with two peaks (one around 0 and the other around 1). I have provided an example of one of the distributions.
[image]
Although their means and variances are different, they both have peaks around the same x-axis markers. How do I test for difference in means using statistically rigorous approaches? Can I still use a t-test even though the data is not normally distributed?

Comment: It looks like your are in a regime where the central limit theorem would kick in, so you could still do a t-test, but I think a more important question is "why does the data look like this?".  Are those peaks at 0 and 1 actually 0 and 1?  From where do the data originate?

Comment: Can you explain the bounds at 0 and 1. Are these proportions of some kind? Do they include exact 0's and exact 1s?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like a textbook example of using beta regression, which can model values between 0 and 1. It is often used for modeling rates and proportions. The distribution can take on various different shapes, and your distribution looks a lot like a beta distribution with shape parameters of .1 and .2. In R:

```
set.seed(1839); hist(rbeta(1000, .1, .2))
```

[image]

I can simulate two samples from different beta distributions, one with a higher mean, and then do a significance test using the `betareg` function from the `betareg` package in R:

```
set.seed(1839)
y <- c(rbeta(300, .1, .3), rbeta(300, .2, .1))
y <- ifelse(y == 1, .999999, y) # because values must be BETWEEN 0 and 1
x <- rep(c(1, 0), each = 300)
mod <- betareg::betareg(y ~ x)
summary(mod)
```

This returns:

```
Call:
betareg::betareg(formula = y ~ x)

Standardized weighted residuals 2:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-3.8917 -0.5212  0.0366  0.5800  3.0307 

Coefficients (mean model with logit link):
            Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)  0.55237    0.08089   6.828 8.59e-12 ***
x           -1.48921    0.12093 -12.315  < 2e-16 ***

Phi coefficients (precision model with identity link):
      Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(phi)  0.33130    0.01566   21.16   <2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1 

Type of estimator: ML (maximum likelihood)
Log-likelihood:  2806 on 3 Df
Pseudo R-squared: 0.2134
Number of iterations: 19 (BFGS) + 1 (Fisher scoring)
```

I have written explainers on beta regression, with some citations you can check out, both [here](https://static1.squarespace.com/static/58a7d1e52994ca398697a621/t/5a2ebc43e4966b0fab6b02de/1513012293857/betareg_politics.pdf) (using `betareg`) and [here](https://github.com/markhwhiteii/beta_hurdle/blob/master/manuscript/beta_hurdle.pdf) (using `gamlss`)

---

But what if you were to assume normality and do a t-test? Usually, people worry about Type I error with violating assumptions. I simulated data where there was no difference at all between conditions 1000 times with a sample size of 1000:

```
set.seed(1839)
iter <- 1000
n <- 1000
results <- lapply(seq_len(iter), function(zzz) {
  y <- rbeta(n, .2, .3)
  y <- ifelse(y == 1, .999999, y)
  x <- rbinom(n, 1, .5)
  beta_reg <- summary(betareg::betareg(y ~ x))$coef$mean[2, 4] < .05
  t_test <- t.test(y ~ x)$p.value < .05
  c(beta_reg = beta_reg, t_test = t_test)
})
colMeans(do.call(rbind, results))
```

Type I error rates show that it is about .05 for both. So, you're probably fine doing a t-test. But (a) you should ask yourself if the two poles are worth modeling themselves—you could trichotomize the data into low pole/between/high pole if those poles are theoretically or practically meaningful—and (b) beta regression can provide a sanity check; do both a t-test and beta regression. If they agree, then report that.

Comment: Your `betareg` test would usually distinguish between for example $\alpha =0.1, \beta=0.3$ and $\alpha =0.3, \beta=0.9$ even though the underlying distributions had the same mean of $\frac14$